# select highest and lowest temperature within a given timeframe in mysql

Tags: mysql

Havn't been coding in mysql for long time and I'm stuck with a small problem. Tried searching but couldn't find anything that worked.
I've got a table with temp_id, date and temp. I want to show the highest temp within a timeframe (last 24h, last week).
Something like this;

```
select 
    date,
    format(max(temp_c),2) as highest_temp
from temps 
where date between '2019-06-01 00:00:00' and '2019-06-07 23:59:59'
and temp_id = 'fineoffset-temperature-152';
```

This shows the wrong date and with a fixed date-interval, but this is where I need your help. Same goes for showing the lowest temp, but the query should be the same execpt min(temp_c) instead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need one row as result, just use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`.

```
select date, format(temp_c, 2) as highest_temp
from temps 
where date <= now()
  and date >= now() - interval 24 hour
  and temp_id = 'fineoffset-temperature-152'
order by temp_c desc
limit 1
```

This will return the row with the highest temperature within the last 24 hours. If you need it from the last week, you can use

```
and date >= now() - interval 24*7 hour
```

or

```
and date >= now() - interval 7 day
```

or

```
and date >= now() - interval 1 week
```

Note that if two rows are tied (having the same temperature), MySQL may pick one of them "randomly". If you want the result to be consistent and independent from the used indexes, you should extend the ORDER BY clause. In your case you could say "on tie pick the most recent row" - which would be

```
order by temp_c desc, date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

for obtain the rigt date you could use an inner join with the subquery for max temp

```
select date,  format(max(temp_c),2) as highest_temp
from temps 
INNER JOIN (
  select max(temp_c) highest_temp
  from temps 
  where date between '2019-06-01 00:00:00' and '2019-06-07 23:59:59'
    and temp_id = 'fineoffset-temperature-152'; 
) t on t.highest_temp = temps.temp_c 
where date between '2019-06-01 00:00:00' and '2019-06-07 23:59:59'
  and temp_id = 'fineoffset-temperature-152'
```